# Communicating to USB Device

Tags: c, usb, communication

I bought a usb otoscope from the internet and I want to create an application that uses it. When I plug it into the computer, it reads the device as a USB Camera, and I can use the very barebones software supplied to communicate with it. I'm very new to the idea of communicating with usb all together. I've tried to look at some sites like this: http://www.jespersaur.com/drupal/book/export/html/21, that tell me how to reverse engineer a device. I don't know if I'm going down the right path with this...

I've downloaded USB Snoopy and I can't seem to get it to sniff the packets correctly. I also have Crunchbang linux installed on a different computer but I don't know how to sniff it on that either (especially because the drivers are native to windows). All I want is some sort of API/Interfacing functions for me to call and use. How do I go about doing such a thing? I'm able to locate the device on the device manager in windows, and it tells me hardware ID's and such. I can supply any information if necessary. Thank you.

EDIT - Small description I found of the otoscope: http://microscopesimgv.blogspot.com/2012/08/oasis-ehev2-usbplus-20mp-handheld-usb.html

Comment: can you provide some details about the otoscope? Maybe more will click with someone. But, if you have windows only drivers and there is nothing really analogous, or noone else has built drivers for it, you're going to have some work ahead of you.

Comment: Ya, made a small edit, you can see what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

would this tool help you any?[libusbx is a cross-platform user mode library that provides generic access to USB devices](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusbx/?source=directory)
CHEERS!